# can i include a web / app.config by the URL

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

Is it possible to include a app.config by the host in C# .net? So i can load a different connection string and other options?

like

```
if (host == "stackoverflow"){
   //inlcude stackoverflow.config
}else{
   //include  othersite.config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load a configuration file. You should have a look at [ConfigurationManager documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But if you want to use different connection strings you could use it by its name like this. See [Retrieving Connection Strings at Run Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)